# Multiple client calls after page refresh with SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

We have a application with multiple hubs using Signal R 1.1.3, that monitors currently logged on users.  The hub periodically refreshes the user count with the following script

```
     $.extend(sr_users.client, {
    showCurrentUserCount: function (data) {
        console.log("Showing Current Users");
        $('#current-users').html(data);
    }
});
```

Which produces the following line

```
   [xx:xx:xx GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'showCurrentUserCount' on hub 'userhub'.
```

However when the browser is refreshed the above client hub event is called multiple times

```
  [15:40:20 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'showCurrentUserCount' on hub 'userhub'.
  [15:40:20 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)] SignalR: Triggering client hub event 'showCurrentUserCount' on hub 'userhub'.
```

How can I prevent this from happening

Thank you

**Additional Code**

```
    sr_users = $.connection.userhub;
$.connection.hub.logging = true;

    //update any ui when the hub starts
$.connection.hub.start()
    .done(function () {
        sr_users.server.getCurrentUsers()
        .done(function (users) {
            $('#current-users').html(users);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you include the code you use to bind it to SignalR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it! Doh! Put an event subscription on the Hub constructor. Bad idea

```
   public UserHub()
   {
      Connections.Instance.OnPurge += ConnectionsUpdate
   }
```

So each time the page was refreshed the event would be subscribed to.  I have no removed the procedure completely and gave the connection Instance access to the HUbContext from where it can send out to all clients